# Check out files modified outside VS from TFS

Tags: version-control, tfs

If a file is modified in Visual Studio, the files are automatically checked out from Team Foundation Server. However, sometimes there are files not modified in VS, is there command to check out those modified files only?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you download the [Team Foundation Server power tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx), you can use the "tfpt online" command line.

That said, I would try and avoid this way of working.  TFS much prefers to know about files that you are checking out before you start editing them and your interaction with TFS will be much happier if you can do this.

The same power tools can optionally install Windows Explorer integration for TFS which will allow you to check the files out easily outside of Visual Studio.

Comment: you mean "tfpt online /diff /noprompt /recursive" would automatically checkout all my files modified outside of visual studio?

Comment: It would check out all files with the read-only attribute unset and additionally those that have changed without unsetting the r/o flag. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449331/tfpt-online-with-diff-can-it-ignore-the-read-only-attribue

Comment: I suggest keeping the /noprompt off if you have files you'd like to exclude (.dlls, generated files, obj and bin folder)